# "ld: library not found for -lc" in mac big sur

Tags: gcc, redis

I try to writed a redis module by  clone the git project https://github.com/RedisLabs/RedisModulesSDK.git

and type the "Make" command in my mac with big sur version, below message display in the console.

But there is a error "ld: library not found for -lc".
How to fix it. I try the same command in a linux os, it works find.

```
gcc -g -fPIC -O3 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -I../   -c -o util.o util.c
gcc -g -fPIC -O3 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -I../   -c -o strings.o strings.c
gcc -g -fPIC -O3 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -I../   -c -o sds.o sds.c
gcc -g -fPIC -O3 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -I../   -c -o vector.o vector.c
gcc -g -fPIC -O3 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -I../   -c -o alloc.o alloc.c
gcc -g -fPIC -O3 -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused-function -I../   -c -o periodic.o periodic.c
ar rcs librmutil.a util.o strings.o sds.o vector.o alloc.o periodic.o
gcc -I../ -Wall -g -fPIC -lc -lm -std=gnu99     -c -o module.o module.c
clang: warning: -lc: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lm: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
ld -o module.so module.o -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -v  -L../rmutil -lrmutil -lc
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-609.8
BUILD 15:07:46 Dec 18 2020
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 arm64e arm64_32 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    ../rmutil
    /usr/lib
    /usr/local/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Library/Frameworks/
    /System/Library/Frameworks/
ld: library not found for -lc
make[1]: *** [module.so] Error 1
make: *** [module.so] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this error on 11.x+: **ld: library not found for -lc**
the path /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib needs to be added with -L
https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/commit/0a780d32e0ae3997ed2f2d611cee604d1476cdb5